# Is there a union solution for remote file access across platform

Tags: linux, window, file-access

In our application, we have to access files/folders in remote server which run on different OS(windows or linux).

We know we can use the `shared files` between windows server and `scp` between linux servers.

But how about between windows and linux?

BTW, we have to access the files/folders in our source codes.

Comment: `PSCP` is worth a try to transfer between windows and linux. Its a putty tool http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: FTP through fuse-ftpfs, SCP over fuse-sshfs, NFS (pretty works in both systems). Just to work with code you can run something like mercurial server.